# Cypress login at IIS Webserver

Tags: iis, active-directory, cypress, e2e

I have a site, that is hosted on an internal IIS webserver. Access is restricted via authentication against Active Directory. Using Edge or Chrome, access works. Using Firefox, a login prompt username/password is shown, and if submitted it also works.

But when using Cypress for automated E2E testing, I receive a 404 from the IIS and "Logon Method"="Anonymous" is listed as reason. No login prompt is shown, for any Cypress browser (Edge, Chrome, Firefox). How can I manage to access the site / pass active directory login data?

I searched the Cypress doc about [Configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration), but could not find any setting to show the IIS login prompt.